# Show email exist error and also have to accept current email and new email while update

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

> In my code email exist error work if i remove NOT EXISTS from SELECT
>   query...but its also says my current email is exists when i update
>   it...So how to show email exists error in this code but also accept
>   current email while updating it and also accept new email while
>   updating it...maybe in select query will help when changing but i
>   tried many time but its not worked...in my code if i use NOT EXIST
>   select query like i mentioned above in company_profile.php page its
>   shows error like:
>
> ```
> **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in
> ```
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hexinor\company_profile.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\hexinor\company_profile.php on line 14**
>
> ```
> So how to change in select query so my code will work for this email exists error and also accept my current email and new email
> ```
>
> while i updating data...[enter image description here][1]
>
> I tried for more than 2 days but its not work so help me to solve this
>   problem...on any other site its show email exists error only for
>   inserting...not for updating and i need for updating

**company_profile.php**

```
     <?php
    if(isset($_POST['company_id'])) {
        $id = $_POST['company_id'];
        $user = $_SESSION['userr'];
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM companies WHERE email = '".$user."' AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT email FROM companies WHERE company_id = '".$id."')");
        $q = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    }
    ?>
    <div class="item form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="email">Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input type="email" id="modal_email" name="modal_work_email" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['userr']) && $_SESSION['userr'] != '') { echo $q['email']; } else { } ?>">
            <span id="availability"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

 <script>  
        $(document).ready(function(){  
            $('#modal_email').change(function(){
                var mail = $(this).val();

                $.ajax({
                    url:'ajax_company_profile.php',
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{email:mail},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        if(data != '0'){
                            $('#availability').html('<span class="email_valid error">Email already exists</span>');
                            $('#modal_update').attr("disabled", true);
                            $('.email_valid').show();
                        } else{
                            $('.email_valid').remove();
                            $('.email_valid').hide();
                            $('#availability').html('<span class="text-success"></span>');
                            $('#modal_update').attr("disabled", false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });  
    </script>
```

**ajax_company_profile.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config.php');
if(isset($_POST["email"]))
{
 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["email"]);
 $query = "SELECT * FROM companies WHERE email = '".$email."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
 echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
}

if(isset($_POST['modal_uid'])) {
    $id = $_POST['modal_uid'];
    $company = $_POST['modal_company_name'];
    $email = $_POST['modal_work_email'];
    $emp = $_POST['modal_no_of_emp'];

    $query = "UPDATE companies SET company_name = '".$company."', email = '".$email."', no_of_emp = '".$emp."' WHERE company_id = '".$id."'";
    $q = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if($q>0) {
        session_unset();
        $_SESSION['userr'] = $email;
        echo "Success";
    }
} 
?>
```

**this select query not work plzz tell me why**

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM companies WHERE email = '".$user."' NOT EXISTS (SELECT email FROM companies WHERE company_id = '".$c_id."')");
    $q = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

**its shows this error**

*Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\hexinor\company_profile.php on line 10*

**company_profile.php add full code**

```
<?php
session_start();
  if(empty($_SESSION['userr'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
include_once('company_header.php');
    $c_id = isset($_POST['company_id']);
    $user = $_SESSION['userr'];
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM companies WHERE email = '".$user."' NOT EXISTS (SELECT email FROM companies WHERE company_id = '".$c_id."')");
    $q = mysqli_fetch_array($query);


    $c_id=$q['company_id'];
    $query1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT count(*) FROM employee_list WHERE company_id = '".$c_id."'");
    $m=mysqli_fetch_array($query1);


?>
<?php 

 ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

      $('#modal_email').keyup(function(){
        var mail = $('#modal_email').val();
      });

    });
 </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#modal_update').on('click', function(){
            var ui = $('#modal_uid').val();
            var comp = $('#modal_company_name').val();
            var mail = $('#modal_email').val();

            var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
            var validEmail = reg.test(mail);


            console.log('Starting ajax');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax_company_profile.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    modal_uid: ui,
                    modal_company_name: comp,
                    modal_work_email: mail,
                },
                success:function(data){
                    // window.location = "company_profile.php";
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

                <div class="button_edit">
                    <a id="add_button"><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">Edit</button></a>
                </div>
              </ul> 
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                    <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" novalidate="">
                      <span class="section">Personal Info</span>
                      <?php if(!$q['company_name']==''){ ?>
                      <div class="item form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="Company">Company
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <input class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 input-box" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['userr']) && $_SESSION['userr'] != '') { echo $q['company_name']; } else { } ?>" readonly>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <?php } ?>
                      <?php if(!$q['email']==''){ ?>
                      <div class="item form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="email">Email
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <input type="email" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 input-box" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['userr']) && $_SESSION['userr'] != '') { echo $q['email']; } else { } ?>" readonly>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <?php } ?>
                      <div class="ln_solid"></div>                     
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Personal Info</h2>
        <button type="button" class="close close-model-trigger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="x_content41">
            <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
              <div class="item form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="company">Company <span class="required">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <input id="modal_company_name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="modal_company_name" placeholder="both name(s) e.g Jon Doe" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['userr']) && $_SESSION['userr'] != '') { echo $q['company_name']; } else { } ?>">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="email">Email <span class="required">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <input type="email" id="modal_email" name="modal_work_email" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['userr']) && $_SESSION['userr'] != '') { echo $q['email']; } else { } ?>">
                  <span id="availability"></span>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 button-submit">
                  <input type="hidden" name="modal_uid" id="modal_uid" value="<?= $q['company_id']; ?>">
                  <button id="modal_update" type="button" name="modal_update" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#modal_email').change(function(){

    var mail = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
      url:'ajax_company_profile.php',
      method:"POST",
      data:{email:mail},
      success:function(data)
      {
       if(data != '0')
       {
        $('#availability').html('<span class="email_valid error">Email already exists</span>');
        $('#modal_update').attr("disabled", true);
        $('.email_valid').show();

       }
       else
       {
        $('.email_valid').remove();
        $('.email_valid').hide();
        $('#availability').html('<span class="text-success"></span>');
        $('#modal_update').attr("disabled", false);
       }
      }
     });
  });
 });  
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following sql:

```
insert into table (primaryKey, column1..) values (primaryValue, value1) on duplicate key update column1=values(column1);
```

And, the table should have one primary key, for these table it is the key `company_id`

Comment: $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM companies WHERE email = '".$user."' NOT EXISTS (SELECT email FROM companies WHERE company_id = '".$c_id."')");
    $q = mysqli_fetch_array($query);                  why this query not work                                        
    Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\hexinor\company_profile.php on line 10

Comment: before using `mysqli_fetch_array`, you need to check the `$query` is empty or not

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because you never call **session_start()** method in the first class, which means $user is undefined, because in that particular file, $_SESSION['userr'] doesn't exist. Also, since you are using mysqli, you'd also have to include your database connection file

```
 <?php
session_start(); //You are missing this
include('config.php'); //You are also missing this
if(isset($_POST['company_id'])) {

?>
```